# JCR SQL2 Filtering by path

Tags: jcr-sql2

I'm trying to filter records where the path contains 'renditions' somewhere in the path. I have in the query NOT CONTAINS(s.*, 'renditions') but it returns records with renditions in the middle of the path but not at the end. Any ideas to eliminate all of these records? Is there a way that is faster than a full text search?

Answer (score 3):

I found it.

[jcr:path] NOT LIKE '%renditions%'